# how to get incremental data of mysql based on bin log

Tags: mysql, innodb

use below parameters to using bin log of one single mysql instance:

--log-bin=XXX

--server-id=XXX

--log-bin-index=XXX

--binlog-checksum=CRC32

--binlog_format=ROW

every thing starts from here:

1. read one table with repeatable read isolation level and dump all data into somewhere. meanwhile mark this read transaction by write something unique at the very beginning and very ending of this transaction so I can easily locate this transaction in bin log.
2. when read these data, active transactions are modifying these data at the same time.
3. when finish reading these data by add finish mark and commit this transaction, other transactions modified these data may commit before or after this transaction.
4. how to get precise diff(incremental) of the table data by only reading bin log next time?
5. each time locked table to read is the option, but lock table is heavy load and will be the last option.

are there any other options?

Comment: You are basically describing a non-locking [incremental backup strategy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-policy.html), and are facing the same problems that are solved there (e.g. the "synchronization" you do with your mark is done by flushing the logs). It looks like you could do exactly this with existing tools (dump+flush + the incremental backup). Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly though. Your current attempt to solve the problem seems unsafe without locking, since between mark and select there might be an update to the table.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to avoid lock table operation since it will block the write. but if it is the only safety way to achieve the goal, I think I'll do it.